# Creating Links on a Pie Chart Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hyperlink

I have an image of a Pie Chart with 5 equal sections, i would like to create a rollover for each section which would then produce a pop up tooltip which will contain text as well as each section link to another page.

I realise this may be fairly involved, so I am also toying with the idea of making each of the 5 sections clickable which would then take the user to a bookmark set on the page. But i am still unser of how to seperate the pie chart so that each section is individually linked.

The pie chart has custom text on each of the sections so I'm not able to use and of the generic pie chart solutions i have found. The pie chart is currently made up of one image, i am able to edit the image if required.

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Comment: You can just use CSS3 shapes to form your pie chart and also have them be clickable. Or you could use [google's api](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) or perhaps [something like this](http://mistercss.blogspot.com/p/pie-chart-generator.html). There are lots of resources online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an Image Map. you can read more about them here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

I use Dreamweaver to plot the coordinates but you can find sites online which will let you upload an image and plot the point online.

The finished code would look like this:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
<area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
<area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Comment: Ended up using Dreamweaver to easily craete the Image Maps. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted - Also, with you saying that you could edit the image, most graphics packages like Fireworks or Illustrator also allow you to create a hotspot and export the HTML code which is much easier for you than Dreamweaver.